# data link layer and encapsulation method used for specific types of media?

Tags: osi

I was reading about the OSI model then found this question in the review questions :

> Which layer of the OSI model is responsible for specifying the
> encapsulation method used for specific types of media?

the answer is data link .

Can you please guys explain what does this mean? does it mean that every media (wireless , copper wire , optical...etc.) has its own encapsulation method that can be determined by the data link layer ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it mean that every media (wireless , copper wire ,
> optical...etc.) has its own encapsulation method that can be
> determined by the data link layer ?

Every data-link protocol has its own framing. Ethernet on copper and fiber has the same framing. Wi-Fi has its own framing. PPP, ATM, frame relay, HDLC, token rig, etc. on copper each have their own framing.

It is not the medium (media is the plural of medium), it is the data-link protocol that determines the framing.

Comment: Might be worth adding that different media require different protocols in the *physical* layer, e.g. Gigabit Ethernet over twisted pair, multi-mode, or single-mode fiber uses 1000BASE-T, 1000BASE-SX, or 1000BASE-LX, respectively.